# What is meant by: "each particle in the observable universe contains 1.509 bits?"

Tags: universe, information

What do physicists generally mean by particles "storing" bits and the idea that information is neither created nor destroyed?

Example:

> "We determined that each particle in the observable universe contains 1.509 bits of information and there are ∼6 × 1080 bits of information stored in all the matter particles of the observable universe."

https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0064475

I have seen this sort of claim made in many books, papers, and lectures. I don't understand how it can be true. The fundemental nature of information is difference, right? So, how can a particle store information simpliciter? Wouldn't the information exist as the relation of values where the particle is versus where it is not?

Also, does the "void" generate new information by way of virtual particles, things like quark condensate, etc.? These seem to get excluded from such analyses. However, for us to measure these things, their presence must somehow vary from their absence, else how can they effect any instruments?

The way I understand conservation of information, it is based on the idea that if you had perfect information about the universe you should be able to evolve it forward with total accuracy.

However, if I have perfect information about a billiard table and can predict an upcoming shot, it does not follow that state S1 before the shot and state S2 after the shot are the same thing or indistinguishable for me. If earlier states of the table, or the universe, have perfect mutual information between the states S1 and S2, it still seems that recording all the information in the universe at one instant (S1) is not the same thing as recording all the states of the universe (S1 to S max).

If the two were truly equivalent then Le Place's Demon should never be able to tell which state of the universe it is looking at, and yet it seems obvious that the universe does have states that differ from one another. It also seems like the Kolmogorov Complexity of a low entropy state of the universe would be less than a higher entropy one simply due to greater regularity.

What am I missing here? Does conservation of information require a block universe view where change is illusory?

Comment: There are interesting questions to be asked about this sort of thing. But the particular linked paper is close to crackpot.

Comment: The calcs or the idea of particles storing information in general? The other places I have seen this sort of thing mentioned were Vlatko Vedral's "Decoding Reality," Max Tegmark's "Our Mathematical Universe," Ben Schumacher's Teaching Company course on information, and an anthology edited by Paul Davies where two papers mention it, plus probably some others. It seems speculative for sure, but also a somewhat common way of speculating, which seems weird to me in that it seems fundementally flawed.

Comment: I suppose the other thing bothering me is that if you accept the "it from bit," premise of some physicists, the aforementioned problems seem to me to imply that things only exist relationally, similar to formalism in mathematics: "a number is what it does." But most versions of "everything is information," just seem to replace particles with bits or qubits. I am either missing something or this swap doesn't work.